# Postman test failing on 'undefined' variable in response

Tags: javascript, json

I am not very familiar with Javascript and Postmen tests, so I might be overlooking something completely. Anyway I have a simple API that queries a mongo DB and returns a 'Student'.

The raw response is:

```
"{\"_id\": \"63e8b7406e2fd8d4555554be\", 
\"first_name\": \"DeJorr\", 
\"gradeRecords\": [{\"grade\": 6.027456183070403, 
                  \"subject_name\": \"subject_name\"}, 
                  {\"grade\": 6.027456183070403, \"subject_name\": \"subject_name\"}], 
    \"last_name\": \"ThisisALastname\"}"
```

Here is my postman test:

```
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

first_name = "DeJorr"
tests["Type: "+typeof jsonData] = jsonData.first_name == first_name;
tests["JSONDATA: "+jsonData] = jsonData.first_name == first_name;
tests["First Name: "+jsonData.first_name] = jsonData.first_name == first_name;
```

So in the logs of that failing tests, see screenshot, we can see that the 'jsonData' var is a string instead of an object. That is why the rest is failing.

[image]
Any ideas as to why JSON.parse(responseBody) does not produce an object?

If i copy the raw response to a JavaScript REPL all works fine..

EDIT:

Server side code, the dumps function is from BSON.json_util. The DB queried is a mongoDB.

```
def get_by_id(student_id=None, subject=None):
    try:
        student = collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(student_id)})
        if not student:
            return 'not found', 404
    except:
        # Invalid ID formats simply return not found
        log.warning("Invalid ID")
        return 'not found', 404

    # Works with double JSON parse client side:
    return dumps(student)

    # Works normally client side:
    student["_id"] = str(student["_id"])
    return student
```

Comment: can you share how are you initializing `responseBody ` ?

Comment: I am not initializing 'responseBody' I believe that is a Postman build-in variable. I logged the type of 'responseBody' as well, which is string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the raw response is

```
"{\"_id\": \"63e8b7406e2fd8d4555554be\", 
\"first_name\": \"DeJorr\", 
\"gradeRecords\": [{\"grade\": 6.027456183070403, 
                  \"subject_name\": \"subject_name\"}, 
                  {\"grade\": 6.027456183070403, \"subject_name\": \"subject_name\"}], 
    \"last_name\": \"ThisisALastname\"}"
```

then it is indeed the JSON representation of another string, that is, of the string

```
{"_id": "63e8b7406e2fd8d4555554be",
"first_name": "DeJorr",
"gradeRecords": [{"grade": 6.027456183070403,
                  "subject_name": "subject_name"},
                  {"grade": 6.027456183070403, "subject_name": "subject_name"}],
    "last_name": "ThisisALastname"}
```

and `JSON.parse` of this latter string gives you a Javascript object. So you would need

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(responseBody));
```

But I would expect a JSON response from the server, so it should already return the latter string. Can you share the server-side code?

Comment: That works, I was thinking it might be server side. I've added the code in the original question. 

And I have just figured out if I remove the 'dumps' function and just return it works.. Although I have to convert the mongo _id field (object) to a string for that to work.